# android looking for onClick handler in ContextThemeWrapper

Tags: android

In 4.0.3 if i am using a base theme in my manifest, it appears to Android is trying to resolve my onClick methods of my menu's in the android.view.ContextThemeWrapper class. It resolves fine in 4.03+. I can take out the style in the manifest and everything works and gets resolved. How can I get the onClick methods to resolve correctly while using a theme?

I'm inflating the menu in the onCreateOptionsMenue() method and that's where the exception is getting thrown.

> android.view.InflateException: Couldn't resolve menu item onClick
>   handler createNewDoc in class android.view.ContextThemeWrapper
>           at android.view.MenuInflater$InflatedOnMenuItemClickListener.(MenuInflater.java:202)
>           at android.view.MenuInflater$MenuState.setItem(MenuInflater.java:402)
>           at android.view.MenuInflater$MenuState.addItem(MenuInflater.java:436)
>           at android.view.MenuInflater.parseMenu(MenuInflater.java:173)
>           at android.view.MenuInflater.inflate(MenuInflater.java:95)
>           at com.c2crm.c2crm.ListActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(ListActivity.java:326)
>           at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2444)
>           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:388)
>           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.invalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:739)
>           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:2833)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
>           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>           Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: createNewDoc [interface android.view.MenuItem]
>           at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
>           at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:915)
>           at android.view.MenuInflater$InflatedOnMenuItemClickListener.(MenuInflater.java:200)